# Highcharts vertical blocks with interval like calendar

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to create a graph kind of like the iCal week-view, with vertical bars but with some space between them according to their from/to value?

I currently have an experimental jsfiddle on the wrong axis, and I would like to invert this: have the weekdays on the x-axis and the hours on the y-axis. Then you would get some vertical blocks for each day with intervals between them. But mapping the values from the y-axis to the x-axis and vice-versa doesn't work. Does somebody have advice to achieve this?

Check out my [Jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/5mW1l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Highcharts rather than HighStock, you can specify 'inverted:true' for the chart options:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    inverted:true
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Vcn9/

This doesn't work for highstock though, so if you need the range selector at the bottom, you will have to invert your data yourself I think.

Comment: I don't really need the range selector, so thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for!